# Limiting file listing by filename length in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am currently generating a list of links (to files in a single directory) using this PHP script:

```
### BEGIN Directory Listing
PHP script to list files in a dir, currently lists dummy files as well, but it works.

<?php
$dir="./content"; // Directory where files are stored
if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false) {
        //this kills the annoying .. and . directory listing
        if($filename == ".." || $filename == ".") continue; ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a></p> 
<?php
}
closedir($dir_list);
}
?>
### END Directory Listing
```

I now wish to only list files with a filename length of 8 characters (the ./content folder contains multiple length filenames but only one filetype). It should also be noted, the files do NOT show/have file extensions.

As always, your help and knowledge is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, instant answer x4. Not sure who's answer to use as "the answer" since you are all correct. I'm going with the first answer, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false) {
        if(strlen($filename) !== 8) continue;
        //this kills the annoying .. and . directory listing
        if($filename == ".." || $filename == ".") continue; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the length with `strlen()`

```
if (strlen($filename) !== 8) continue;
```

Comment: He said "only list files with a filename length of 8 characters"

Comment: @vodich yes, this will skip the current iteration if the filename is not exactly 8 characters

Comment: @vodich And?... Doing it your way creates [arrow-code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)

Comment: As I am looking at it I wouldn't skip it but put == 8 and don't use else since he wants only those files right?

Comment: @vodich Read that post on arrow code. It explains why you want to avoid nesting control structures. It might make sense, logically, to do what you're suggesting but when it comes to readability and maintainability it's a no no.

Comment: Read it and you are right but in this case I see only one if satatement so it's not that big deal. Here is one post about arrow code http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Check it with `strlen()` function

if(strlen($filename) ==8)){
   //do something }